# SQL - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Pivot table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I'm trying to set up my databse and add some foreign keys but allways getting the following errror :

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I have 3 tables.

```
groups, categories and categorie_group
```

the categorie_group table is my pivot table. It only contains a categorie_id and a group_id

Both can be NULL.

groups and cateogires have ID as a primary key

All 3 tables don't have any data yet.

```
Groups Table: 

The ID references the categorie_group - group_id
- on delete cascade on update cascade

Categorie_Group
the group_id of categorie_group references the id of the groups table
on delete no action on update no action

the categorie_id of categorie_group references the id of the categories 
table on delete no action on update no action

-------
```

First problem:

If I want to add a foreign key from the `Categories Table` ID to the `categorie_Group` -> `categorie_id` -

I get a

```
ALTER TABLE `categories` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `id` ) REFERENCES `DB`.`categorie_group` (
`categorie_id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL meldet: Dokumentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB`.`#sql-c40_30a2caf`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-c40_30a2caf_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `categorie_group` (`categorie_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

seccond Problem, if I want to add data to the groups table I get the same error.

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DB`.`group`, CONSTRAINT `group_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `categorie_group` (`group_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You must implement the FK in the child column "categorie_id", not on PK "id". The PK "id" must be referenced and "categorie_id" must do the reference.
- Be sure about the column attributes propertyes. Both (primaryKey and FK) must be the same. Or SGBD can't solve the FK:

1- '**Datatype**'. The Type (INT, SMALLINT) property as the Size property;
2- '**Accept Null**'.
3- '**Unsigned**'.

- Remember that MyISAM table engine doesn't accept FK constraints, just InnoDB does.

Good Luck.

Comment: I will try that. But "Accept Null" are only for the FK right? not for the PK right?

Comment: I've gave every PK and FK an "unsigend" and all share the same datatype. Accept Null is only for the FK. But this haven't worked for me

Comment: What about the tables engines? Remember that MyISAM doesn't accept FK constraints, just InnoDB does.

Comment: Yes I'm using InnoDB

Comment: I tried set up the tables new. Deleted all 3 and made them new. Same error

Comment: I'm reading your constraint again. You must implement the FK in the child column "categorie_id", and not on PK "id". 
The PK "id" must be referenced and "categorie_id" do the reference.